# Displaying contents of list in body of email with Python and smtplib

Tags: python, smtplib

I would like to loop through a list and display each item on a separate line in my email.

The code works fine if I set body = "Just a string"

```
mylist = [first line,second line,third line,fourth line]

fromaddr = "EMAIL"
toaddr = "EMAIL"
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "EMAIL SUBJECT"

body = mylist
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login("EMAIL", "PASSWORD")
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
```

I tried just making body = to mylist just to see how it looked currently but I get the following error: _text.encode('us-ascii')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

What I would like ultimately is the body of the email to look this (when I receive the email):

first line
second line
third line
fourth line

Comment: You must convert your list to a string first. In your case the string method "join" can help. For the beginning you can also try "str(mylist)" but this won't exactly produce what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Michael Butscher for the push in the right direction.

This does the job.

```
body = "\r\n".join(mylist)
```